# Angular 1 - concatenate model with string in expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

Is there a possibility of having this writing in an expression with ecmaScript 2015 for example, it is especially the `||` that cause problem i think

```
{{ ::$ctrl.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct.housingTax + ' €' || $ctrl.noDataMessage }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular filter

```
myApp.filter('xyz', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if(input) {
      return input + ' €';
    } else {
      $ctrl.noDataMessage;
    }
  };
});
```

in HTML

```
{{$ctrl.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct.housingTax | xyz }}
```